# IBM DB2 Bundle with IIS using HADR and Tivoli

Tags: ibm-information-server

I want confirm whether DB2 ESE bundled with IIS can be used to set up the DB2 repository as cluster DB2 using HADR and Tivoli system Automation manager. Is the bundled license permit supported for configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the licensing docs for your purchase (standalone DataStage, Data Quality bundle, Data Integration bundle, or Enterprise Edition bundle).
Here is a search for ‘Information Server Enterprise’ on the license documents: http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/searchlis/?searchview&searchorder=4&searchmax=0&query=(Information+Server+Enterprise)